# Permanently Delete RSS Feeds in Outlook.Application VB script

Tags: vba, outlook

I am looking to permanently delete RSS feeds from outlook 2003/2007 with a VB script.

I was wondering if there was a way to do this without emptying the recycling bin as users sometimes use the recycling bin as folder.

Below is a sample of the code I have so far any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

```
Const olFolderRssFeeds = 25 
Dim olkApp, olkSes, olkFld, olkSub, intIdx, intCount 

Set olkApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 
Set olkSes = olkApp.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
'Change the profile name on the next line' 
olkSes.Logon "Outlook" 

Set olkFld = olkSes.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderRssFeeds) 
Wscript.echo(olkFld)  

intCount = olkFld.Folders.count 
Wscript.echo("Folder Count: " & intCount)  


For intIdx = intcount to 1 step -1 
   Set olkSub = olkFld.Folders.item(intIdx) 
   'Wscript.echo("Feed Name: " & olkSub)  
   olkSub.PermanentDelete 
Next 

Set olkSub = Nothing 
Set olkFld = Nothing 
olkSes.Logoff 
Set olkSes = Nothing 
Set olkApp = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll basically need to run the Delete twice.  You can do this by recording the `EntryID` before the first delete, so that you can recover the item and delete it again.

```
olkSubEntryID = olkSub.EntryID
olkSub.Detele
Set olkSub = olkSes.GetItemFromID(olkSubEntryID)
olkSub.Delete
```